# Transforming time series gridded meteorological data from .csv file to multiple .shp files (one per date) with pyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I downloaded gridded meteorological data as .csv file from the JRC CGMS database for a territory of interest. The file has data for predefined point locations over the territory in a regular-spacing grid. The data are daily and cover a period, say 1 year. So, in the .csv file there is a separate row for each combination of point and date (for example, we have 365 rows for the same point, each with data for particular date; then the next 365 rows for the next point. etc). The data also include geographic coordinates of the points.

I would like to automatically handle such data with the final goal of obtaining, let say, 365 shapefiles, each containing meteorological attributes from the .csv for a single date for all points.

Sample of the data (1 month; 2 points only) can be obtained from this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0v5764swgewsdrd/Gridded_AgroMet_Data_Europe_ver2_0_sample2.csv?dl=0

What I tried so far is to open the .csv file in QGIS and export as a point shapefile. This shapefile, however has, for each point, 365 features lying on top of each other. I want a python script to select features based on the 'DAY' attribute end export in new shapefile. And I want this procedure to iterate over all unique values of the attribute 'DAY'. So far my script is just that:

```
shapefile = iface.activeLayer()
selection= shapefile.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("\"DAY\"='20150101'"))
shapefile.selectByIds([s.id() for s in selection])
```

How to continue from here? How to export the selection? How to iterate between dates?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Would you be willing to use `gdal` instead of `PyQGIS`?

Comment: Do u absolutely want to achieve this **programmatically** or do u accept any other method ? ;-p

Comment: Welcome! you might want to have a look at the NetCDF file format, It seems better suited for your needs

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I do not mind to use gdal if this is a convenient way, but I am unfamiliar with gdal as well as with PyQGIS. In all cases I should start from the beginning. I can do this manually but it will take several days and errors are very probable. I would prefer an automated way. The JRC site provides the data only in CSV file format. Should I convert them in NetCDF myself? Is this possible? What software should I use?

Comment: Geopandas and pandas would be suitable for this. I can post an answer if you are ok with using these libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the .csv file ("**add delimited text layer**" - CRS : **WGS 84** - X and Y being the longitude and latitude attributes).

You can save it as a shape file or any format if necessary.
In the Processing Toolbox you choose "**split vector layer**", as "unique ID Field" you choose "DAY" and the toolbox generates the awaited files ...

You're done ...

Being a toolbox treatement it should not be too hard to automate this (*some posts describe the procedure*)...

*(not sure about the NetCDF proposal ... i don't think it will make your life easier for what u seem to be awaiting ...)*

Comment: I did not know about this "split vector layer" tool. It did exactly what I wanted, and so easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) libraries. Install these in your existing qgis python environment or install [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) (and then `conda install geopandas`).

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import os

csvfile = '/home/bera/Downloads/Gridded_AgroMet_Data_Europe_ver2_0_sample2.csv'
out_shapefile_folder = '/home/bera/Downloads/Outshapes/'

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, delimiter=';') #Create pandas dataframe from csv

#Create geodataframe from dataframe
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.LONGITUDE, df.LATITUDE)]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} #4326 correct?
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

#Iterate over each day and export shapefile
for day, group in gdf.groupby(by='DAY'):
    group.to_file(os.path.join(out_shapefile_folder,'Raindata_date_{0}.shp'.format(day)))
```

[image]

I dont know what your next step is but when the data is in pandas/geopandas you can do **alot** of analysis. Might be easier than handling all output shapefiles.

Comment: This seems to be very smart and elegant solution as well. Thanks. You are right. I will have to find a way to handle all this shp files now that I have them. I need to create raster files from the point vectors and maybe to linearly interpolate between points, i.e. to have a raster with resolution (somewhat) higher than the spacing of the original points. But this is another story.